# Variable passed as a key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I define a variable `a = 42` and I pass it to a dictionary `di = {a: 'fourty-two'}`. How does Python read the key in  `di`?
 `a` as a variable or number that `a` is referring to?

In case that key is just a reference to some number, does redefining ( let's say `a = 10` ) change the key in `di`?
Could someone clarify it to me?
Thank you!

**EDIT :**
When I change value of variable `a` to 10, why key in `di` doesn't change

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: Do you mean `a` instead of `x`?

Comment: I do not get what you mean with "*pass it to a dictionary*"? How do you pass it?

Comment: Pass value as a variable. I don't set it to `di = {42: 'fourty-two}` but i define it via variable `a`

Comment: What you do is 100% equivalent to `di = {42: 'fourty-two'}`, as simple checks show (including simply `print(di)`). What do you think might happen? The one thing that emphatically doesn't happen is that `di` is modified by later binding `a` to another value.

Comment: Keys are immutable. Are you asking why you can't mutate an immutable key?

Comment: When i define a variable and use it through the program, all these calls of variable are just a reference to something else ( number, string, list etc ). When  I change the value of this variable, it is changed all over the code. I'm asking why this doesn't work with keys

Comment: `di[10] = di.pop(42)` ?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski The use of `pop()` is more elegant than the two-step process I suggested in my answer. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in a dictionary are immutable. You can't make them variable.
Consider:

```
>>> a = 42
>>> di = {a:'forty-two'}
>>> di
{42: 'forty-two'}
```

The dictionary itself simply has `42` as the key. The fact that you used `a` in setting up the dictionary is quite irrelevant. Similarly, since `a` is 42, if I write `b = a + 1` then `b` will be `43`, and this fact won't be changed if I later change `a` to `10`. In that case `b` won't magically become `11`.

If you do want to bind `a` to a new number and use that new number as the key, you would need to manually modify the dictionary:

```
>>> old_a = a #store old value of a
>>> a = 10 #assign new value to a
>>> di[a] = di[old_a] #assign value to new key
>>> del(di[old_a]) #delete old key-value pair
>>> di
{10: 'forty-two'}
```

This is somewhat convoluted, which suggests that it isn't very pythonic and that there is probably a better way to do whatever it is that you are trying to do.

**On Edit** The process of swapping keys can be streamlined by using `.pop()`, as @ŁukaszRogalski, points out in a comment above:

```
old_a = a
a = 10
di[a] = d.pop(old_a)
```

This way automatically deletes the old key in the process of assigning its value to the new key.

Comment: Thank you for answer!  
It helps , but code i use is a bit complicated and it does exact opposite (list `a` is changed by `a.append()`  and all  things binded to `a` also changed)

Comment: If `a` refers to a list it can't be used to create a key of a dictionary.

Comment: As i said, it's a bit complicated. I use class to create hash of that list in case list is used as a key

Comment: @SevO If you find a way to hash a list, then what the hash itself would be sort of an immutable snapshot of the list at the point when you hashed it. If you used the hash as a key it would still be an immutable key. Perhaps you could create your own class which inherits from `dict`, a sort of dictionary with updatable keys class. The process of switching keys that I had in my answer could be extracted to a method, as well as your way of getting a hash of a list.